# How to store the most recently opened content of infowindow into a variable in Google Map aspx Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have designed the Google map displaying multiple locations in the form of Markers. Now my requirement is whenever i click any marker, its content, that appears in the info-window, should get stored into some variable and the variable's content can be updated on re-click of any marker.

Here is the code i have used....

> Google Maps Multiple
>   Markers
>
> var info_var;
>           var locarr =[];
>           locarr[0]="Khilwat,Charminar,Hyderabad";
>         locarr[1]="Lower Tank Bund Rd, Hyderabad";
>
> ```
>   geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
>
>   var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
>   var mapOptions = {
>       zoom: 10,
>       center: latlng,
>       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
>   }
>
>   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
>
>   var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
>
>   for (var i = 0; i < locarr.length; i++) {
>
>       var Mycontent=locarr[i];
>
>       (function(Mycontent) {
>
>       geocoder.geocode({ 'address': locarr[i] }, function (results, status) {
>
>           if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
>               map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
>               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
>                   map: map,
>                   position: results[0].geometry.location
>               });
>
>                 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
>                 infowindow.setContent(Mycontent);
>
>                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i,Mycontent) {
>                                 return function(Mycontent) {                                        
>                                   infowindow.open(map, marker);             
>                                 }
>                            })(marker, i,Mycontent));
>
>                            bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
>
>           } //if ends
>
>           else
>             {
>               alert('Geocode was not successful for the reason: ' + status);
>             }
>
>       });// geocode ends here :-
>      })(Mycontent);//anonymous func ends here 
>
>   } //for ends
> ```

Thanks in advance for your Help !

Comment: Could you please share some code, how you are attaching to click event of marker.

Comment: I have shared the used code.....